# Multiplication Table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a simple multiplication table in JavaScript with two nested for loops:

```
var result = '\n';
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        result += (i*j) + ' ';
    }
    result += '\n'
}
```

[image: See screenshot of browser console results]

The first position is 1, but I want it to start with an empty first position, or an "X" for example, so that the result of 1 * 1 is also displayed like here

[image: Screenshot of desired result]

Comment: The result should be printed in console in that format or you want to show that in browser?

Comment: I am not getting it, you want it in a table ?

Comment: You can define `var result = 'X '`; The loop is appending to `result`

Comment: For console output, [`result += ' '.repeat(3 - (i * j).toString().length) + (i * j) + ' ';`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/m6bamkkx/)

Comment: Yes, I want it to look like a table but do not want to involve HTML here in order to keep it simple. Tushar, the jsfiddle example outputs the same as what I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = 'x ';
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {

        if(i == 0 && j > 0){
          result += '[' + j + ']';
        } 
        else if(j == 0 && i>0){
          result += '[' + i + '] ';
        } 
        else if(i>0 && j>0){
        result += (i*j) + ' ';
        }
    }
    result += '\n'
}

console.log(result);
```

*Output:*

```
x [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
[2] 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
[3] 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
[4] 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 
[5] 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 
[6] 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 
[7] 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 
[8] 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 
[9] 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 
[10] 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

---

for better printing:

```
var result = ' x   ';

function buff(val){
  var buff = '';
  var pad = 4 - val;
    while( pad-- > 0 )
            buff += ' ';            
  return buff;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {

        if(i == 0 && j > 0){
          result += '[' + j + ']' + buff((j+'').length+2);
        } 
        else if(j == 0 && i>0){
          result += '[' + i + ']';
        } 
        else if(i>0 && j>0){
        result += buff((i*j+'').length ) + i*j;
        }
    }
    result += '\n'
}
```

*Output:*

```
 x   [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
[2]   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
[3]   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
[4]   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
[5]   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
[6]   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
[7]   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
[8]   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
[9]   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
[10]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

Comment: I like the logic here. I have used something similar using php and smarty for a client in creating this multiplication table https://math.tools/table/multiplication . Thank you for the inspiration.

Comment: I am not a huge fan of adding empty string to a number as String conversion. For explicit purposes, I prefer to use buff((j.toString()) instead of  buff((j+''), and buff((i * j).toString() instead of buff((i * j + ''). Otherwise, awesome - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.write("<center><table border='1px'>");
for (var a = 1; a < 11; a++) {
  document.write("<tr style='height:40px'>");
  for (var b = 1; b < 11; b++) {
    document.write("<td style='width:40px'><center><font size='4'>" + a * b + "</center></font></td>");
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table></center>");
```

Comment: Hi @Babak, a great way to add even more value to an answer is just one or two lines explaining what is changed and why. Also has the benifit of improving SEO :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var table = 1;
    var count = 12;
       for (var m =0; m < count; m++) {
    m++

document.write(table, "X", m, "=", table * m+'<br>');
--m
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple one here will display just like you would see it in a school textbook

```js
let res = " x\t 1\t 2\t 3\t 4\t 5\t 6\t 7\t 8\t 9\t10"
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    res += `\n${i < 10 ? ' ' + i : i}`
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        res += `\t${i * j >= 10 ? i*j : ' ' + i*j}`
    }
}
console.log(res)
```

So we only need to consider the spaces, tabs and newlines the rest is straight forward

**Output**

```
 x     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 2     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20
 3     3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30
 4     4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40
 5     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50
 6     6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54    60
 7     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70
 8     8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80
 9     9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81    90
10    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90    100
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var table = 5;
    var count = 12;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        i++;
        console.log(table, "X", i, "=", table * i);
        --i;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.write("<center><table border='5px'>");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            document.write("<td><center>" + i * j);
    }
document.write("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).